# Pip install from GitHub repo throws wheel error

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

When I run:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.mycompany.com/developer/sdk-python.git@master#egg=sdk-python
```

I see this output:

```
Cloning ssh://git@github.mycompany.com/developer/sdk-python.git (to revision master) to /private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-install-txsz9E/sdk-python
Generating metadata for package sdk-python produced metadata for project name sdk. Fix your #egg=sdk-python fragments.
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sdk) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sdk) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sdk) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sdk) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sdk) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sdk) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->sdk) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sdk, sdk
  Building wheel for sdk (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-twLUBT/wheels/e5/b9/06/c754f4c2a0a2b191960dabcfc6f1dc7d0bb231e844cf4a032e
  Building wheel for sdk (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/me/git/sdk-python-test/venv27/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-install-txsz9E/sdk/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-wheel-OIQ_lk --python-tag cp27:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-install-txsz9E/sdk/setup.py'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for sdk
  Running setup.py clean for sdk
  Complete output from command /Users/me/git/sdk-python-test/venv27/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-install-txsz9E/sdk/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-install-txsz9E/sdk/setup.py'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for sdk
Successfully built sdk
Failed to build sdk
Installing collected packages: sdk
Successfully installed sdk-1.0.0
```

It looks to me as if sdk-python installed. I can even see it if I do `pip list`. However,  I don't understand the errors. Other similar posts suggest missing depedencies but I ca't see anything that's missing.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Below is my setup.py. I believe it is correct but it's my first time creating one so I based it mstly on something I found online so it may not be correct. If there is anything obviously wrong with it I'd be keen to hear what that is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# sdk python version check
_valid  =  sys.version_info[:2] == (2,7) or sys.version_info >= (3,4)
if not _valid:
    sys.exit("Sorry, SDK only supports versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 of python.")


ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
VERSION_RE = re.compile(r'''__version__ = ['"]([a-z0-9._-]+)['"]''')

requirements = [
    'requests',
    'python-dateutil'
]


def get_version():
    init = open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'sdk', '__init__.py')).read()
    return VERSION_RE.search(init).group(1)


setup(
    name='sdk',
    version=get_version(),
    description='SDK for Python',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author='me',
    url='https://github.mycompany.com/developer/sdk-python',
    scripts=[],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires = requirements,
    license="Apache License 2.0",
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    ],
)
```

**Additional Info**

It installs without issue if I run this:

```
pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.mycompany.com/developer/sdk-python.git@master#egg=sdk-python
```

Should I be including the `-e`? I always thought it was optional and only would have used it if I wanted to edit the package.

Comment: have you correctly written a `setup.py` file in the root directory of sdk-python. [See packaging python projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: I added the `setup.py` as I believe it to be correct but as mentioned in my question, it's my 1st time creating one so have quite possibly done something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name in my `setup.py` is `sdk` but the name I use for my egg is `sdk-python`. These should be the same from what I can tell.

I changed my command to this and it worked:

```
pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.mycompany.com/developer/sdk-python.git@master#egg=sdk
```