# Install python package from bitbucket in non-editable mode

Tags: python, pip, bitbucket, setuptools

I'm trying to install a python package from a private bitbucket repository into a virtual env, but pip does not seem to install any files. When using the following command (*norman* is the package's name):

```
pip3 install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git@develop#egg=norman
```

the installation is successful but there is no *norman* folder in `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`, so it seems that nothing was installed, even if `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/norman=0.1.0.dist-info` is indeed there.

Yet, the installation works perfectly using a tar.gz archive made with `python3 setup.py sdist` then installing with `pip3 install path_to_norman.tar.gz`.

Following [these indications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106992/pip-install-from-github-repo-throws-wheel-error), I also tried to install the package in editable mode :

```
pip3 install -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git@develop#egg=norman
```

This worked fine and installed the files (in `venv/src`), but I'd prefer installing it in non-editable mode. What should I do to make the installation work in non-editable mode ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from python `__init__.py` files which were not included in the remote repo, so the package installed by `pip3 install git+ssh...` was actually empty.

When building the archive on a local machine, they were obviously there, and when using `-e` option, as the whole repo is downloaded, the python scripts were there anyway.

When not using `-e`, from what I understand, pip creates a temporary local download of the files available and then builds the package normally. Since init files were not downloaded, python scripts were not recognized by `setuptools`, thus an empty package was installed.